# SSH username and password

Tags: windows, ssh, cisco

I've installed Cisco SDM, it asks for SSH username and password.

I don't remember setting it before.

How can I change or see SSH username and password?

BTW, I'm running Windows Server 2003.

Comment: did you try cisco cisco

Comment: or read the manual... where you'll find what egorgry said.

Answer (score 1):

It is 'cisco' and 'cisco', otherwise you'll need to reset the switch to defaults.